# How to fix the Heroku web-deployment error (ex:H10) from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, web-deployment, webdeploy

## Problem Summary

- I got H10 error from accessing my website which is deployed from Heroku.
- It runs in a local server without any issues.
- The error happened after I updated the NPM then deployed to the Heroku.
- The detailed NPM error says "cannot find module" and "failed start script"

How should I fix this issue?

## Previous approaches

I have searched the solutions to this problem and checked my port setting, procfile, package.json, and .gitignore, but I am still getting the error.

## Examples of codes

**my port setting in app.js**

```
> let port = process.env.PORT; if (port == null || port == "") {   port
> = 3000; }
> 
> app.listen(port,function() {   console.log("Server started on port
> 3000"); });
```

**package.json**

```
> {   "name": "todolist-v1",   "version": "1.0.0",   "description": "", 
> "main": "app.js",   "scripts": {
>     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
>     "start": "node app.js"
> 
>   },   "author": "",   "license": "ISC",   "engines": {
>     "node": "10.14.2"
> 
>   },   "dependencies": {
>     "async": "^2.6.2",
>     "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
>     "date-and-time": "^0.6.3",
>     "ejs": "^2.6.1",
>     "express": "^4.16.4",
>     "jsqr": "^1.2.0",
>     "lodash": "^4.17.11",
>     "moment": "^2.24.0",
>     "mongoose": "^5.5.2"   } }
```

**.gitignore**

```
/node_modules
npm-debug.log
.DS_Store
/*.env
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node app.js
```

**heroku error**

```
2019-04-24T05:37:09.064416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-thicket-75018.herokuapp.com request_id=8d2ebd1c-0e87-4048-aa63-667672ad11a2 fwd="129.128.60.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**NPM error**

```
Error: Cannot find module '../wireprotocol/constants'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/sdam/topology_description.js:5:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todolist-v1@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the todolist-v1@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```